# Cannot resolve symbol 'SamlServerConfiguration' in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, saml-2.0

I have a spring-boot project where I'm trying to create a SAML2 identity provider (IdP) using `spring-boot-starter-security` (v2.1.4.RELEASE) and `spring-security-saml2-core` (v1.0.9.RELEASE) packages. I'm basically trying to customize and build the code that is in https://github.com/fhanik/springone2018/blob/master/demo/saml-idp. However, when I build my code, I get the following errors:

> package org.springframework.security.saml.provider does not exist
>
> cannot find symbol
>     symbol: class SamlServerConfiguration

I believe I have included all the required packages that are mentioned in the reference implementation, so not really sure why I'm getting this error.

Following are the files in my project.

**AppConfig.java** (file containing the error):

```
package com.example.saml.identityprovider;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.saml.provider.SamlServerConfiguration; // error: package does not exist

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.security.saml2")
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends SamlServerConfiguration {  // error: symbol not found
}
```

**Application.java** (file containing **main**):

```
package com.example.saml.identityprovider;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    /**
     * Returns the homepage message.
     *
     * @return String message
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getHome() {
        logger.info("Received request for '/' endpoint");
        return "This is a SAML identity provider.";
    }

    /**
     * Provides SPs to select from.
     *
     * @return String
     */
    @RequestMapping("/selectsp")
    public String selectProvider() {
        logger.info("Sample IdP application - Select an SP");
        return "redirect:/saml/idp/select";
    }

    /**
     * Main method.
     *
     * @param args Command-line args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example.saml</groupId>
    <artifactId>identityprovider</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.extensions/spring-security-saml2-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If someone could point me as to what I might be missing, I'd really appreciate. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @theprogrammer Nope, I couldn't.

Comment: I just downloaded their github project, so its working for me temporarily. However if anyone is interested, maybe you could surround dependencies in pom.xml with <dependencymanagement> tag. it might work. just putting it out here, not sure if it works 100%.